# create three column, two of them fixed position

Tags: css, position

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/weemy/p4fMV/)
I have three columns, but i want the right and the left column, fixed position, when i scroll the page these columns comes with scrolling, my problem is, i can't make both of them fixed in their position, and i have another issue with i18n, that when i change from rtl to ltr.

css

```
    body{
    background:#fff;    
    margin:0px auto 0px auto ;
    padding:0px auto 0px auto ;

}
html{
    background:#fff;    
    margin:0px auto 0px auto ;
    padding:0px auto 0px auto ;
}

.inner-page{
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    padding:0px auto 0px auto;
    position: relative;
}
.inner-navbar{
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    padding:0px auto 0px auto;
    width:1000px;
}
.inner-page-right{
    background: #000; 
    width:200px;
    min-height:1000px;
            color:#fff;
            float:right
}
.inner-page-center{
    width:600px;
    min-height:1000px;
            float:right
}
.inner-page-left{
    background: #000; 
    width:200px;
    min-height:1000px;
            color:#fff;
            float:left
}
.inner-page-center-up{
    height:50px;
}
.inner-page-center-down{
    background-color:#e6e6e6;
    border:1px solid #cccccc;   
}
```

and Html

```
<div class="inner-page inner-navbar">
    <div class="inner-page-right" >
        column right
    </div><!--inner-page-big-right_right-->
    <div class="inner-page-center">
            column center
    </div><!--inner-page-big-right_right-->
    <div class="inner-page-left">
        column left
    </div><!--inner-page-big-left-->
</div><!--inner-page-->
```

Comment: Is this what you want to do? http://jsfiddle.net/p4fMV/1/

Comment: sorry, but not exactly, i want to make this columns inside the .inner-page, so the columns will see inside the left part and right part of .inner-page, thank you @3dgoo

Comment: I think we need some clarification. You have a three column page.  You left column and your right column you want fixed. Your center column you want scrollable (3dgoo gave a good example). Your comment needs to be clarified. Do you want your center column to expand under your left and right columns?

Comment: i just want, when the user scroll the page, just the center part scrolling, and the right and left stay in their in position .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the left and right columns using `position: fixed`. We place them in the correct position by placing them in the centre with `right: 50%` / `left: 50%` and then shifting them across by half the width of the container with `margin-right: -500px` / `margin-left: -500px`:

**CSS**

```
.inner-page-right {
    ...
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -500px;
}
.inner-page-left {
    ...
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -500px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p4fMV/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done with pure css. 
You could set your two in absolute position and update their top value using a javascript scroll event to keep them always on top of your navigator.

Comment: can you give an example for this dynamic value of top absolute position ?